# What is the best way to access data from a particular field in wireshark decoded packets

Tags: wireshark, pyshark

I am using **wireshark** to decode *gsm* packets. **Wireshark** picks up all communication at that frequency and decodes it.
[Overview of the packets obtained.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwCdY.png)

Now in the system information 5 packet, we have the required parameter.[Details of system information 5 packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyrRZ.png)

I wish to write a code such that if there is only a single value in the last entry of the packet i.e. the neighbour list, an alert inform of a pop up message or something is generated.
These packets have to captured and processed in real time.
I have installed pyshark but cant figure out how to move forward.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I can only give a partial answer, which is how to detect if there's only a single value or not.  My suggestion is to use [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) and then post-process the data using another tool, such as [`wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc).  For example:

```
tshark -i lo -Y "gsm_a.rr.arfcn_list" -T fields -e gsm_a.rr.arfcn_list | wc -w
```

If the result is 1, then there's only 1 entry in the list.

How you generate an alert from this, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thankyou so much. However there is a problem with the code. From my understanding, this code increments the number of nearby ARFCNs whenever the system information packet is received (which is quite a number of times). I just want the number of neighbour ARFCNs when the packet appears the first time.

Comment: Moreover, further in the list of packets received, there is a packet called paging request 2. It contains the field IMSI/TMSI. I also need to write the code to find out if the field is empty or has a particular value.

Comment: Is there anyway I can restrict the number of packets under observation?